# Case Insensitive Search - swiftui iOS15

Tags: search, swiftui, ios15

**Case Insensitive Search - swiftui iOS15**

I want user to search through an array case insensitive. So far I achieved this through lowercasing both array item and the search bar text. I wonder if there is a simpler way?

```
var searchResults: [Array] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return filteredArray
        } else {
            return filteredArray.filter {
                $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
        }
    }
```

Comment: efficient way worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*More efficient* is more important than *simpler*.

More efficient ways are

```
$0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
```

and

```
$0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
```